# THREEJS - Can not get the jpg to load as the material map property when the material is assigned to an object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am not able to get the camo.jpg graphic to skin the bow.

`camo.jpg` that I want to assign to the riser child object: [image]

Here is the bow once three.js renders it:
[image]

Here is the results from console.log:
[image]

I am getting the data. Here is the complete code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <title>CBE</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="bow-model-wrapper"></div>

    <div id="product-config"></div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/three.js"></script>

    <script>
        var scene = new THREE.Scene()
        var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader()
        var canvasWidth = 664
        var canvasHeight = 601
        var viewSize = 100 // 664
        var aspectRatio = canvasWidth / canvasHeight
        var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-aspectRatio * viewSize / 2, aspectRatio * viewSize / 2, viewSize / 2, -viewSize / 2, -40, 80)
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true})
        var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader()
        textureLoader.load(
          'https://<url>/images/green-camo.jpg',
          function (texture) {
            var riserTextureMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({needsUpdate: true, map: texture})

            loader.load('https://<url>/bow-3d-models/complete-bow-decimated.json', function (object) {
              scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff)

              renderer.setSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight)

              document.querySelector('#bow-model-wrapper').appendChild(renderer.domElement)

              var canvas = document.querySelector('#bow-model-wrapper canvas')

              var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x2194ce, emissive: 0x224172, shading: THREE.SmoothShading})
              var camMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x000000, emissive: 0x3c4047, specular: 0xffffff, shininess: 1, shading: THREE.SmoothShading})
              var limbMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x000000, emissive: 0x000000, specular: 0xffffff, shininess: 1, shading: THREE.SmoothShading})
              var riserMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()
              object.scale.x = object.scale.y = object.scale.z = 15

              object.traverse(function (child) {

                  switch (child.name) {

                    case 'riser':
                      child.material.needsUpdate = true
                      child.material = riserTextureMaterial
                      break

                    case 'string-suppressor-base':
                      child.material = limbMaterial
                      break

                    case 'upper-cam':
                      child.material = camMaterial
                      break

                    case 'upper-inner-cam':
                      child.material = camMaterial
                      break

                    case 'upper-limb':
                      child.material = limbMaterial
                      break

                    case 'upper-limb-pocket':
                      child.material = limbMaterial
                      break

                    case 'lower-outer-cam':
                      child.material = camMaterial
                      break

                    case 'lower-inner-cam':
                      child.material = camMaterial
                      break

                    case 'lower-cam-bearings':
                      child.material = camMaterial
                      break

                    case 'lower-limb':
                      child.material = limbMaterial
                      break

                      case 'lower-limb-pocket':
                        child.material = limbMaterial
                        break

                    default:
                      child.material = material
                      break
                  }
                  // scene.add(object)

                })


                            scene.add(object, camera)

                var light = new THREE.PointLight( {color: 0xffffff, intensity: 0.25, distance: 15, decay: 5} )
                    light.position.set( 10, 0, 10 )
                    scene.add( light )

                var light2 = new THREE.HemisphereLight( {skyColor: 0x404040, groundColor: 0x404040, intensity: 0.1} )
                    light2.position.set( 0, -10, 0 )
                    scene.add( light2 )

                camera.position.y = 0
                camera.position.y = 0
                camera.position.z = 0

                object.translateY(-51)

                var render = function () {

                  object.rotation.y += 0.007
                  window.requestAnimationFrame(render)
                  renderer.render(scene, camera)
                }

                render()
            })
          },
                function (xhr) {
                    console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' )
                },
                function (xhr) {
                    console.log('error')
                })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I get the camo to skin the bow?

Comment: I have not assigned textures in blender. I am assuming that the camo.jpg can be used to skin the bow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go into Blender and create a UV map. Then re-export for three.js and include the UV.

How to create a UV map in blender is explained here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1022/adding-uv-mapping-to-mesh